# Express routing with undefined depth

Tags: express

I want to create SEO friendly route for an e-commerce shop with ExpressJS but I don't know how.

Route for category : catalog/category1/category2/category3

Route for product : catalog/category1/category2/category3/product-name

The problem is that there is an undefined depth of categories, some category have a grandparent and parent category, some just have a parent and some are root category.
How can I solve this ? Is this appropriate for SEO ?

Answer (score 0):

If you start your middleware like this

```js
app.use("/catalog", function(req, res, next) {
  var categories = req.path.split("/");
  categories.shift();
  var product = catagories.pop();
  if (product is actually a category) {
    categories.push(product);
    product = undefined;
  }
  ...
});
```

a request for a product route will give you `categories = ["category1", "category2", ...]` and `product = "product-name"`.

The only issue is that you must somehow be able to differentiate between routes that end in a category and routes that end in a product, based solely on the putative `product` name.